# Selenium weird behavior, element not clickable when it's there

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I run a multithread python selenium script which gives me unexpected behavior which I can not understand. So after opening a new browser I try to clear the cache with below code ;

```
 driver.get('chrome://settings/clearBrowserData')

 WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//settings-ui')))
 driver.find_element_by_xpath('//settings-ui').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

90 out of 100 times this works but sometimes it throws me this error :

```
 element not interactable
```

To my understanding somehow the page is not loaded fully and selenium is too "fast".
However I do wait until the element is visible which would eliminate this plus to my understanding the driver.get also waits until the "full get" is returned and finished.

Can someone explain me why this behavior occurs ?
Sub question would be is my understanding right driver.get(page) waits for full page loading done ?

Answer (score 0):

The `ElementNotInteractableException` exception can occur for a few reasons:

1. The element that you want to interact with is disabled.
2. There's an overlay element covering the one you want to interact with, such as a loading spinner.

If it's 1, use `EC.element_to_be_clickable` instead of `EC.visibility_of_element_located`.

If it's 2, you'll need to either wait for the overlay element to go away on it's own. Or, perform an action to make the overlay element go away.